# How to I parse a JSON file to display it's elements in a html table cells

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a dashboard which is a table with multiple columns and rows. I have a URL(provided by the backend team) which has JSON data. Now, I have to read that data from that URL and display it in the cells of the HTML table.

I have to use something called asynchronous calls so that the latest data from the database is shown in the table. I tried following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mT3r8Qn1VY and like how he's using a JSON file, so have I tried to use a JSON file. But, I don't get anything in my console.log unlike him. I am new to javascript and don't really know how to go about it. I know the basic concept that I have to loop over the file and change the inner HTML of each cell, but I can't get started.

The HTML file is like this for one row:

```
<head>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"> 
      </script>

           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

            <script src="daterange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script src="get-data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <br>
       <h1>Demo Request Customer Database</h1>
        <br>
         <div class="">
        <form  class="row" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="myinput" placeholder="Search by email..." name="" value="">

        <input type="text" name="daterange" id="date-range" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />

                 <input type="submit" name="" value="Save changes" id="save_button">

        </form>
        </div>
        <table cellpadding="5" style="width:100%;" id="mytable" class="fixed">



    <thead>
               <tr class="header" id="header" style="color:#ffffff">
                 <th class="tab_header">Email</th>
                 <th class="tab_header">Name</th>
                 <th class="tab_header">Position</th>
                </tr></thead>
<tbody id="body_rows">
                </tbody>



      </table>

        <br>


    </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript file is :

```
function setup(){
      loadJSON("example.json",gotData);}

      function gotData(data){
          console.log(data);
      }
```

The example.JSON file is :

```
    [
      {
            "email": "abhinav@musiio.com",
             "name": "Abhinav",
             "position":"software eng"

        },
    ]
```

I basically want to capture JSON data from a URL that will be provided to me by the backend team. But for the time being, I am trying to display the JSON data in the HTML row from the example.JSON file.

Comment: Load the data from your endpoint with the fetch API and loop through the content to output the results.

Comment: Ah Fetch API , I am not sure how to use it. Do you have a code snippet. Also , once I fetch data from the fetch API , can I store it in a file and then loop over that file to display it in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` instead of 2 rows with different classes in your `<tbody>`

I'll give you a simple example so you can do something similar:

```js
let data = [{
  "email": "abhinav@musiio.com",
  "name": "Abhinav",
  "position": "software eng"
}, ];

let htmlString = '';
for (let row of data) {
  htmlString = '<tr>';
  htmlString += `<td>${row.email}</td>`;
  htmlString += `<td>${row.name}</td>`;
  htmlString += `<td>${row.position}</td>`;
  htmlString += '</tr>';
}

document.getElementById('body_rows').innerHTML = htmlString;
```

```html
<table class="column3 tworow" style="background-color:#bbb;" align="center" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header" style="color:#ffffff">
      <th class="tab_header">Email</th>
      <th class="tab_header">Name</th>
      <th class="tab_header">Position</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body_rows">
    <!--This will be filled by Javascript-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Mate! a few points : 1)  I get a warning for "let" and "of" and tells me use es6version. 2) the variable data is in the same file as the javascript, right? If yes then , how will I read the JSON data later on from a URL and put it here? Also, no data is displayed in the html table :(

Comment: Ok resolved the warning but data is still not displayed. I get this error in console:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null . Where did I go wrong. I deleted whatever was there in table_rows to be filled by the JAvascript

Comment: @user2702225 you must have the tag `<tbody id="body_rows">` instead of `<tr id="body_rows" style="color:#ffffff">`

Comment: yeah did that .. still the same issue :(

Comment: I don't see a reason why your code  shouldn't work... It's pretty straightforward... I wonder why this strange behavior

Comment: Update the question with your updated HTML and Javascript please so I can have a look, or you can also use https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @user2702225 u have a missing double quote in `<table cellpadding="5" style="width:100% ; id="mytable" class="fixed">` after `"width:100%` and 2 tags are not closed, add  `</table></body>` to the end of your posted html

Comment: @user2702225 will you please update your code again so I can help you? also add the javascript part, if you can add a snippet that shows the error it would be perfect.

Comment: nevermind ... Now I have to implement everything in react.... Do lemme know if you are comfortable in react. facing a lot of problems  ..Thanks for all the help ! really appreciate